# In Stripe is there any method to make a standalone payment when user clicks on a link which is received in email?

Tags: php, email, stripe-payments

I have a situation where a user have to make a payment once user receives an email.The problem is, the email which the user receives should contain a link which when clicked by the user it should send the user to stripe account of the merchant and pay to that particular merchant and redirect to a custom url with all the status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a feature that Stripe offers directly. Stripe does not host payment forms at this time -- the entire payment flow takes place on the Stripe user's site.

Using Stripe's API, you could build something like what you described. You can also take a look at existing third-party integrations that specialize in invoicing: https://stripe.com/works-with/categories/invoicing